# Array of flags in Objective C and Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am building a class which shall store an array of flags, specifically one yes/no flag per month of year. I want the flag storage to be private, initialized to "no" state on class construction, with methods to set and get flags.

What would be the most clean Objective C/Cocoa way to do this?

Comment: Can you show us some of the not clean ways you have tried? And tell us why it does not work.

Comment: @Bernd why not write some of your code. No one is here to steal it!!

Comment: Plain old C is the cleanest *and* the fastest (no need to box/unbox objects). Thus `BOOL flags[12]` is the way to go. You might want to learn about boolean algebra, though.

Comment: @Cyrille Actually, I'ds use the C99 type `bool`

Comment: @JeremyP Actually I'd `typedef unsigned short int flagsType` and use `flagsType flags &= 1 << month` to toggle a bit on, but that's a matter of personal taste.

Comment: You might want to consider various calendars available in NSCalendar. Not everyone uses Gregorian. Not all calendars have same number of months.

Answer (score 1):

```
@implementation AClass
{
    bool monthFlags[12]; // automatically initialised to all false on creation
}

-(void) setFlagValue: (bool) newValue forMonth: (size_t) aMonth
{
    if (aMonth < 12)
    {
        monthFlags[aMonth] = newValue;
    }
    else
    {
        // exception probably
    }
}

-(bool) flagValueForMonth: (size_t) aMonth
{
    if (aMonth < 12)
    {
        return monthFlags[aMonth];
    }
    else
    {
        // exception probably
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way seems to be using c array . Create  a property and set all values to 0.
You can do that in a single step. `array[12] = {0}` . Then you can get set values from index and use them as booleans. Since BOOL represents 0/1, you do not need any conversion.

Answer (score -1):

```
@interface MyArray:NSObject
@end

@implementation{
    NSArray *array;
}
-(id) init{
    if(self = [super init]){
        array = [NSMutableArray array];
        for(int i=0; i<12; i++){
            array[i] = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
        }
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) setFlag:(BOOL)b forMonth:(int)idx{
    if(idx>=12 || idx<0) return;
    array[idx] = [NSNumber numberWithBool:b];
}

-(BOOL) flagForMonth:(int)idx{
    if(idx>=12 || idx<0) return NO;
    return [array[idx] boolValue];
}
@end
```

Comment: Method naming is terrible. `setFlag:forMonth:` and `flagForMonth:` would be the correct names. There are other problems (magic numbers, signed/unsigned) but that's not so important.

Comment: By the way, the code won't even compile (array not mutable).

Comment: @Sulthan thank you. I wrote directly, so made some mistakes. 1) Your method name is more clear. 2) magic numbers is a problem. 3) NSArray should be NSMutableArray. 4) but what's the signed/unsigned problem?